# Drupal URL Rewriting conflict

Tags: regex, drupal, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have Drupal 7 installed in the root directory of my site. The .htaccess file hasn't been modified since installation.

However, I also have CodeIgniter set up in a subdirectory. I created a .htaccess file in the CI directory with the suggested instructions to remove index.php from the url.

eg. mysite.com/subsite/index.php/blog --> mysite.com/subsite/blog

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Unfortunately doesn't work. I assume Drupal's .htaccess rules are conflicting. What rules should I write Drupal's .htaccess to enable the CodeIgniter rewriting rules?

Many thanks

**EDIT**:  Solution is, immediately after the *RewriteEngine on* rule in Drupal's .htaccess, I inserted

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^ci_site/(.*)$ ci_site/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Hopefully this helps anyone who has a similar setup.

Comment: I've just worked it out! Immediately after the `RewriteEngine on` rule in Drupal's .htaccess, I inserted `RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)` then `RewriteRule ^ci_site/(.*)$ ci_site/index.php/$1 [L]` without any problems. For anyone who has a similar setup.

Comment: Put your solution in an answer, and once the allotted time has passed, mark it accepted :)

Comment: As Laxman said, you should answer it and mark your answer accepted, otherwise it keeps appearing in lists of unanswered questions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy from the question. I landed here wanting to help somebody and, after reading the question, I saw the solution inside...

The solution is, immediately after the RewriteEngine on rule in Drupal's .htaccess, inserting

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^ci_site/(.*)$ ci_site/index.php/$1 [L]
```