# How can i ascertain database connection info for php mysqli from drupal files?

Tags: php, database, drupal

I have full access to ftp and even phpmyadmin remotely for a project but i am implementing a separate php module for site and I therefore need to connect to the database with mysql statements in php.

All I see in drupal files to connect with is a url.

I don't know drupal but I have a very good knowledge on php.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL (`$db_url` variable) in your sites/default/settings.php file is broken down like this:

`protocol://username:password@server/databasename`

You should be able to apply that to your own `$db_url` and get the connection details.

Comment: thank you.  works fine.  now I just need to figure out which htaccess rules to changed so code igniter works right along with the drupal install.

Comment: You'll find that here: [Drupal URL Rewriting conflict](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749399/drupal-url-rewriting-conflict) :)